# Changing the Album on FLAC files from the command line in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, metadata, flac

I have a folder of FLACs that I want to change the album on. I use Ubuntu linux with Gnome. Is there a command line program that can do what I need? I can't seem to find an appropriate program.

Ideally it would be something like...

```
flacchange --Album NewAlbumName *.flac
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metaflac is what you want
http://flac.sourceforge.net/documentation_tools_metaflac.html

Comment: You should give a minimal working example in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with the `metaflac` tool ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/metaflac)), which should be available from the `flac` package (I use debian).

You want to remove the old tag first, and then add the tag again with the correct values. Here is the artist tag for example:

```
metaflac --remove-tag=artist *.flac
metaflac --set-tag=artist="Beyoncé" *.flac
```

And here's a short demo of changing the artist tag on a couple of example files:

```
$ ls
11 - All Night.flac  12 - Formation.flac

$ metaflac --show-tag=artist *.flac
11 - All Night.flac:ARTIST=Beyonce
12 - Formation.flac:ARTIST=Beyonce

$ metaflac --remove-tag=artist *.flac
$ metaflac --show-tag=artist *.flac

$ metaflac --set-tag=artist="Beyoncé" *.flac
$ metaflac --show-tag=artist *.flac
11 - All Night.flac:artist=Beyoncé
12 - Formation.flac:artist=Beyoncé
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a general command-line tagger that should work the same for any music file regardless of the format, try `pytags`, included in the `pytagsfs` package.

Comment: ooo, that looks interesting.  bonus, it uses mutagen as the tagging library.

Comment: Yeah, mutagen is a giant bucket of win. Ditto Quod Libet/Ex Falso. I was previously using `mid3v2`, the mutagen-based reimplementation of `id3v2`, along with a local customization to support multiple tag values. But since pytags does this already, and for all file types, I suppose I'll switch over to it.

Comment: might wanna rethink -- i read pytagsfs currently uses mutagen's EasyID3 interface so doesn't support all the tags ExFalso will.  tho that may be the same as mid3v2, i can't recall.  i always just used EF for any multi-tag use (only needed multiple genre tags anyways, and only tagging mp3s).

Comment: Hmm. You're right. It seems that the magical format-agnostic tagging ability is built into Quod Libet/Ex Falso, not mutagen itself.